# TSQL Pivoting multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Code:

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE
    (
        [Employee_Id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
      , [Code]        NVARCHAR(10)
    ) ;

INSERT INTO @Employee
VALUES ( N'E1' ), ( N'E2' ), ( N'E3' ) ;

DECLARE @Contact TABLE
    (
        [Employee_Id]  INT
      , [PhoneType]    CHAR(1)
      , [PhoneNumber]  VARCHAR(20)
      , [IsMainNumber] BIT
    ) ;

INSERT INTO @Contact
VALUES (1, 'M', '1234567890', 1), (1, 'H', '1234567891', 0),
       (1, 'M', '1234567892', 0), (1, 'B', '1234567893', 0),
       (2, 'M', '2234567890', 0), (2, 'H', '2234567891', 1),
       (2, 'B', '2234567892', 0), (2, 'M', '2234567893', 0),
       (3, 'M', '3234567890', 0), (3, 'H', '3234567891', 0),
       (3, 'M', '3234567892', 0), (3, 'B', '3234567893', 1);

SELECT  
    [E].[Employee_Id],
    [E].[Code],
    [COA].[MainPhoneNumber],
    [COA].[NonMainNumber]
FROM
    @Employee AS [E]
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT      
         MAX (IIF([C].[IsMainNumber] = 1, [C].[PhoneNumber], NULL)) [MainPhoneNumber],
         MAX (IIF([C].[IsMainNumber] = 0, [C].[PhoneNumber], NULL)) [NonMainNumber]
     FROM        
         @Contact AS [C]
     WHERE       
         [E].[Employee_Id] = [C].[Employee_Id]
     GROUP BY    
         [C].[Employee_Id]) AS [COA] ;
```

Current output

```
Employee_Id Code    MainPhoneNumber NonMainNumber
1           E1      1234567890      1234567893
2           E2      2234567891      2234567893
3           E3      3234567893      3234567892
```

Goal

I need to return the MAX main phone number and its phone type and MAX non-main phone number and its phone type. I'm able to get the MAX main/non-main phone numbers, but need to somehow get their phone types. I don't want to make two additional joins based on Employee_Id and PhoneNumber and get the type, because original table is huge and that would slow things down a lot. Trying to figure out an alternative that performs well.

Desired Output

```
Employee_Id Code    MainPhoneType   MainPhoneNumber NonMainPhoneType    NonMainNumber
1           E1      M               1234567890      B                   1234567893
2           E2      H               2234567891      M                   2234567893
3           E3      B               3234567893      M                   3234567892
```

Comment: Did you actually try using joins and know the performance? Do you have indexes? I don't think that's a huge problem. If that really is a problem, you could do it the dirty way - concatenate types to your phone numbers when getting MAX value and then just substring it to create other columns.

Comment: I've sample data and the table has index on Employee_Id and PhoneNumber. But still want to find a better way than joining to the contact table 2 more times. it would have a lot of rows... a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need two `apply` :

```
select e.Employee_Id, e.Code, 
       c.PhoneType as MainPhoneType, c.PhoneNumber as MainPhoneNumber, 
       c1.PhoneType as NonMainPhoneType, c1.PhoneNumber as NonMainNumber
from @Employee e outer apply
     (select top (1) c.PhoneType, c.PhoneNumber
      from @Contact c
      where c.Employee_Id = e.Employee_Id and
            c.IsMainNumber = 1
      order by c.phonetype 
     ) c outer apply 
     (select top (1) c1.PhoneType, c1.PhoneNumber
      from @Contact c1
      where c1.Employee_Id = e.Employee_Id and
            c1.IsMainNumber = 0
      order by c1.phonetype 
     ) c1;
```

If you don't want to do `JOIN` two times then you can use temp table just dump the contacts with relevant `index`

> **#temp (Employee_Id, IsMainNumber) include (PhoneType, PhoneNumber)**

```
insert into #temp (Employee_Id, PhoneType, PhoneNumber, IsMainNumber)
    select Employee_Id, PhoneType, PhoneNumber, IsMainNumber
    from (select *, row_number() over (partition by Employee_Id, IsMainNumber order by PhoneType) as seq
          from @Contact
         ) c
     where seq = 1
```

Now, you don't need to use `@Contact` again :

```
select e.*, m.*
from @Employee e cross apply
     (select max(case when t.IsMainNumber = 1 then t.PhoneType end) as MainPhoneType, 
             max(case when t.IsMainNumber = 1 then t.PhoneNumber end) as MainPhoneNumber,
             max(case when t.IsMainNumber = 0 then t.PhoneType end) as NonMainPhoneType, 
             max(case when t.IsMainNumber = 0 then t.PhoneNumber end) as NonMainNumber
      from #temp t
      where t.Employee_Id = e.Employee_Id               
     ) m;
```

Comment: Thank you for a neat alternative. Though, if possible, I'm trying to avoid multiple joins to the @contacts table (doesn't even have to be outer apply).

Comment: Your last query is not quite right. You can't ensure that the same row will be returned in your subquery for the NonMainNumber. Meaning that Max PhoneType may or may not be the type that is associated with the Max PhoneNumber. Well actually it would be the same row but no real way to define which row it would be.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure how you determine which nonMainNumber is the one you want. Seems that most of your sample data has several rows that could be returned. I will leave that exercise to you. Here is how you could use some conditional aggregation for this.

```
select x.Employee_Id
    , x.Code
    , MainPhoneType = max(case when x.RowNum = 1 then x.PhoneType end)
    , MainPhoneNumber = max(case when x.RowNum = 1 then x.PhoneNumber end)
    , NonMainPhoneType = max(case when x.RowNum = 2 then x.PhoneType end)
    , NonMainPhoneNumber = max(case when x.RowNum = 2 then x.PhoneNumber end)
from
(
    select e.Employee_Id
        , e.Code
        , c.PhoneType
        , c.PhoneNumber
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by e.Employee_Id order by c.IsMainNumber desc, c.PhoneType) --Not sure how you determine the non MainNumber when there are several to pick from
    from @Employee e
    join @Contact c on c.Employee_Id = e.Employee_Id
) x
group by x.Employee_Id
    , x.Code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select e.Employee_Id, e.Code
       max(case when seqnum = 1 and c.PhoneType = 'M' then c.PhoneType end) as MainPhoneType
       max(case when seqnum = 1  and c.PhoneType = 'M' then x.PhoneNumber end) as MainPhoneNumber,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 and c.PhoneType <> 'M' then c.PhoneType end) as NonMainPhoneType
       max(case when seqnum = 1  and c.PhoneType <> 'M' then c.PhoneNumber end) as NonMainPhoneNumber
from @Employee e join
     (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by c.Employee_Id
                                             (case when PhoneType = 'M' then  'M' end)
                                order by c.PhoneNumber desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from @Contact c
     ) c
     on c.Employee_Id = e.Employee_Id
group by e.Employee_Id, e.Code;
```

The key idea in this logic is the `partition by` clause.  It divides the two types of phones into two groups -- with `'M'` for "main" and `NULL` for all else.